# redirect to current page if user clicks back or refreshes the page

Tags: php, post

Sorry I have posted this question and I googled it alot still Im unable to solve this

I have a php page that has a form and when user clicks refresh or F5 it creates duplicate values in the database and also a message is alerted to the user, indicating resubmitting may insert duplicate values in database.My boss dont want that alert box of the browser to user and also insertion of duplicate values into the database

I know its `header()`. I read lot of `header()` in php manual and also `server_name` functions but still I tried in many ways putting in the top but cant solve it. its very important. can anyone please help me with a sample of code explaining the way to do.any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 <form method="post" action"demo.php">
  <input name="fname" type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
 demo.php
  <?php
   $firstname = $_POST['fname'];
   ?>
```

Tell me what should i add in the demo.php page to stop it from submitting the form again and again and also if user clicks back button on the browser it should not direct to the previous page , it should still redirect to current page.

So if user clicks refresh or back button it should redirect to current page only and should not insert any duplicate values and also alert box should be disabled.Please explain me what to do here, im in deep help.Thanks

Comment: after submitting your form, you should to reload your page with javascript `location.href='url'`. By the way are you not using any framework or architecture or CMS etc?

Comment: @J.J. what you mean you are not using any framework ?im kinda new to php . kindly let me know if i need to use any framework

Comment: Have you listen about ZEND,MVC,Magento,joomla,Typo3 etc. ?

Comment: @J.J. not really what are they

Comment: @all kindly explain me with some html and php page sorry but i read all those on google but im unable to put the things in order thats what im asking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use php header function to replace the current location so if the user clicks refresh, it won't repost the information and a session to store the posted value and check for resubmissions.
demo.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_POST)
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION[fname]))
    {
        //database queries here
    }
    $_SESSION[fname] = $_POST['fname'];
    header('location:demo.php', true);  //true replaces the current location
}elseif(!issset($_SESSION[fname])){
    header('location:form.php');
}

$firstname = $_SESSION[fname];

?>
```

form.php

```
<form method="post" action"demo.php">
  <input name="fname" type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of things wrong with your code, and lots of ways to mitigate the impact.

First, why are you creating duplicate entries?
In addition to the problem of bad data is also implies that your site is vulnerable to CSRF. Go read up on how to prevent CSRF with single-use tokens.

If you've got performance problems with your site, then users will often click on the submit button multiple times. While addressing the duplicate submission problem on the database, use javascript to disable the submit links on the page and provide visual feedback that the page is doing something.

Redirects are not the way to solve the problem.

> My boss dont want that alert box of the browser

Are you talking about the duplicate post alert? While you can get around this using PRG, that creates other problems.

Comment: yes i dont want an alert box popped out from a browser , can you kindly explain me with writing php and html pages so that i understand, people telling me to add this and redirect all thos but still im not finding a solution i need a better solution i need php and html page samples to understand instead of directly posting a link to it

Answer (score 1):

You must post a unique id (session_id) and save it in the database.
When your registration, test if the session_id is already present. If so, send a message to THE USER. "You have already post out this form"

The code:

```
<?php session_start; ?>
    <form method="post" action"demo.php">
      <input name="fname" type="text">
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
      <input type="hidden" name="session_id" value="<?php echo session_id();?>">
     </form>
     demo.php
      <?php
      //test session_id in database
      $session_id = session_id();
      mysql_connect('localhost','xxx','xxx');
      mysql_select_db('xxx');
      $return = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb_data FROM TABLENAME WHERE session_id='".session_id()."'");
      $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($return);
      if ($data['nb_data'] == 0){
            echo 'Your message';
      }
      else{       
            $firstname = $_POST['fname'];
            //.....
            header('location:xxx.php')?
      }
?>
```

Comment: and also how do i avoid the alert box of the browser?

Comment: just insert in place `echo 'Your message';` with `echo '<script>alert(\'your message\')</script>';`

Comment: To be sure to come back and mark whichever answer helped you the most as the "answer" with the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

You need ON DUPLICATE KEY , this will update the record instead of creating a copy of it :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
so it wouldn't matter if they hit refresh or resubmit, if the record existed already it would just get updated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution will be to redirect the page after database operations like insert, update and **delete
pageName: test.php**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['deleteBtn']))
{
$emp_id=$_REQUEST['emp_id'];
$count=mysql_query("delete from employees where emp_id=$emp_id");
header("location:test.php");
}
```

This way if you click F5 or back button the form data will not get posted again.

Comment: @J.J Sab Teek hai ter Kya hal hi?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to embed a session id in your form when you create it, and to track that session id on the server. Then, when the form is submitted and you are processing the form on the server, if the form was submitted more than once, you can overwrite the first submission in your database, or respond with an error message, or whatever. (Show the popup only on the first submission, whatever.)

An easy way to do this is to generate a session id, send it as a hidden field in the form, and when the form is submitted store the session id in your database with the constraint that the session id be unique.